# Strange results for NaiveBayes under Weka's GUI

Tags: user-interface, weka, document-classification

I'm using Weka's GUI to classify text documents. My data set is in the .arff format.

I apply   the StringToWordVector  filter. Then, I apply  the RemovePercentage filter  to divide my data set into train and test set. It contains 99 instances in total and 934 attributes. After train-test splits, train set contains 66 instances and test set contains 33 instances.

I learn the model in the train set: result is 100% as accuracy
Then, I test the model learned on the test set: result is 3.0303 %.

Could anyone help me to understand why I get 3.0303 % and how to improve this result?

Answer (score 2):

The model Naive Bayes learns is [overfitted](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Overfitting). You can try different train/test splits (or [cross validation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-validation_%28statistics%29)) to prevent this. You can also try adjusting the parameters of the Naive Bayes algorithm or using a different one.

Comment: Could you tell me how to do this with Weka's GUI?

Comment: I want to follow the solution provided in this video: [link](https://www.ai-class.com/course/video/videolecture/54) by using Weka's GUI. Could anyone help me?

Comment: The choice of test/training split or cross validation are in the upper half of the left hand column in the prediction window, you can adjust the parameters of an algorithm by clicking on it.

Comment: I want to adjust the parameter k for NaiveBayes classifier but when I click on the NaiveBayes algorithm, I don't see any parameter k.

Comment: I want to find a solution for Naive Bayes Laplacian Smoothing by adjusting the parameter k. My problem is how to adjust the parameter k in the Weka's GUI.

Comment: There's plenty of documentation on Weka, please have a look at that before asking here.

Comment: I tried to find a solution by looking at Weka's documentation and by asking a question on the mailing list but I haven't found what I'm looking for.